# How to understand what this sfdisk command is doing

Tags: ubuntu, bash, partitioning, shell

In this command what is happening? I tried to know but what are these numbers and parameters `2048,,0x0C,-`?

```
sfdisk -u S -L -q ${RAW_FILE} 2>/dev/null << EOF
2048,,0x0C,-
EOF
```

Comment: Please get into the habit of saying ``"$RAW_FILE"`` or `"${RAW_FILE}"` instead of `${RAW_FILE}`.

Comment: No I'll write whatever is written shell script.

Comment: @nikhilchaubey Your loss; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1):

sfdisk has a manual page that you even find [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html). It tells you this:

> start size type bootable

Also, when a field is empty, the default value is assumed. So, `echo , | sfdisk /dev/sdx` creates a single, non-bootable Linux filesystem type (0x83) partition that spans the entire disk.

In your case, the partition starts at sector 2048, i.e. 1Mb, and ends at the end of the disk. The partition is of type 0xC, which means FAT filesystem.

Comment: Yes got it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_0Ch

Answer (score 1):

[ExplainShell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sfdisk+-u+S+-L+-q+%24%7BRAW_FILE%7D):

> **-u**, **--unit** *letter*
>
>   Interpret the input and show the output in the units specified by
>   *letter*
>   .  This
>   *letter*
>   can be  one of  S,  C, B or M, meaning Sectors, Cylinders, Blocks and Megabytes, respectively.  The default is cylinders, at least when the geometry is known.
>
> **-L**, **--Linux**
>
>   Do not complain about things irrelevant for Linux.
>
> **-q**, **--quiet**
>
>   Suppress warning messages.

Essentially "use sectors as a unit and don't complain".

As for the input format, [`man sfdisk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sfdisk.8.html):

> **sfdisk** has four (main) uses: list the size of a partition, list the partitions on a device, check the partitions on a device, and - very dangerous - repartition a device. [...]
>
> **List sizes** 
> `sfdisk -s partition` gives the size of *partition* in blocks.

Your command doesn't use `-s`. Mode 2:

> **List partitions** 
> The second type of invocation:
> `sfdisk -l device` will list the partitions on the specified device.

Your command doesn't use `-l`. Mode 3:

> **Check partitions** 
> The third type of invocation:
> `sfdisk -V device` will apply various consistency checks to the partition tables on *device*.

Your command doesn't use `-V`, so we're left with the 4th mode:

> **Create partitions** 
> The fourth type of invocation:
> `sfdisk device` will cause **sfdisk** to read  the  specification or  the  desired  partitioning  of *device* from  standard  input, and then to change the partition tables on that disk. [...]
>
> BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL - ONE TYPING MISTAKE AND ALL YOUR DATA IS LOST
>
> [...]

> **INPUT FORMAT**
>
> **sfdisk** reads lines of the form
>
> ```
> <start> <size> <id> <bootable> <c,h,s> <c,h,s>
> ```
>
> where each line fills one partition descriptor.
>
> Fields are separated by whitespace, or comma or semicolon possibly followed by whitespace; [...] When a field is absent or empty, a default value is used. [...]
>
> Bootable is specified as [`*`|`-`], with as default not-bootable. [...]
>
> The default value of size is as much as possible (until next partition or end-of-disk).

So your input:

```
2048,,0x0C,-
```

Will create a partition offset 2048 sectors, as large as possible, with ID `0C` hexadecimal ([FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type)) and with the *bootable* flag not set.

Exact offset will depend on sector size of the target drive. With the more common 512-byte sectors it will be 1 MiB.

The partition will not be automatically formatted as FAT32. It will only be marked as intended to be FAT32-formatted.

---

TL;DR: It's all in the manual.

Comment: I got confused with EXT4 which the shell script mentioned some place. Couldn't find 0x0C there. Anyways, well explained answer.

Comment: I can’t find any documentation on this that doesn’t suck (I would suggest that \[`*` | `-`\], with an explanation, would be clearer than “\[\*|-\]”), but my intuition would be that **``-``** in the fourth field (“bootable” flag) means ***non-*** bootable, and [berndbausch’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1657887/150988#1657899) says the same thing.  Are you sure that **`-`** means “with the *bootable* flag set”?  P.S.  I know the documentation says that “M” means Megabytes.  Do you happen to know (through experience, or through reading source code) whether that is correct, or is it Mebibytes?

Comment: @Scott You're correct, `-` means **not** bootable. Corrected, thank you. Regarding the `M` unit, I've tried to check it on the latest GRML (the only ISO I have at hand at the moment) but in its version of `sfdisk` the `-u` option is deprecated and accepts only `S`.